# Some calendar events won't sync on Jelly Bean?

Tags: synchronization, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an application that works well on any version of android prior to Jelly Bean.  I have been pulling my hair out for several days. It seems that the events that I create programatically which show up on my device refuse to be sent to the web calendar.  It does appear that the synchronization in general is faster (hence better), but it seems broken???  Is there anything one must set on the event to allow it to be synchronized, or keep it from being synchronized??

I ask because events that I create by hand using the calendar on the device - they synchronize etc.  The new events I create programmatically do trigger the ChangeObserver on the device and show up on the devices calendar, just not remotely.  So there must be some magic under the covers that keeps these events from being sent and thus saving bandwidth??? -- this is an optimization that I could imagine having been added to Jelly Bean.

If you know of any behaviour like this please let me know.  If not, please let me know if synchronization is working properly on Jelly Bean in any custom app you are involved with.  THANKS VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

The next step will be to build a small test app that can demonstrate this failure.  But I hope that it is easier and one of you already knows about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This took a long time to find.  I hope it helps someone else.
In adding an event, I was calling the usual

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, title);
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, mCalendarTag.mID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
Uri uri = mContentResolver.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Prior to Jelly Bean, this worked fine.  With Jelly Bean, the line:

```
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
```

fails without ANY NOTIFICATION!  This must be changed to:

```
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

Then everything works properly.  The real difficulty is that the event created with getDisplayName() is locally created BUT it is never synchronized remotely. I sure hope that someone else sees this and it saves them several days.